# How can I changed the selected <select> tag element in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a website using Scrapy.

I need to query the list of all existing items of a board-like function on my target site.

The problem is that it only searches within a target year, designated with a  HTML tag option.

So I need to find a way to changed to location "selected" attribute within the s.

I think I'm not really doing my job at describing my troubles, so I'll append a simplified HTML code of the site:

```
<select name="Search_FIS_YEAR" id="Search_FIS_YEAR" title="fiscal_year">
    <option value="2014" selected>2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    ...
    <option value="2007">2011</option>
</select>
```

So the default value of my target website is 2014, but I want to programmatically change its value to 2013, 2012, etc.

The search query is sent through a large  that makes a POST request method to the server.

Fortunately I found a way to send the query using FormRequest.from_response, but I wasn't really successful in modifying the above part of the code.

Comment: The messy way that I have in mind is to parse the response text. I'm pretty sure that this is not the way I want though

Answer (score 0):

I already knew the answer.

All I did was to just change the value of  option within the form data:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formname=NAME_OF_FORM_WRAPPING_SELECT_HTML_ELEMENT
    formdata={
        'Search_FIS_YEAR': '2013', # or any other year value
    }
    callback=self.other_parse_function
)
```

This did all the tricks for me.